# Shuffle Js is not working even thoughI have using append method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shuffle

I use https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/ plugin to shuffle my feed, but I have a problem when try to collaborate this plugin with load more features.

And also, I was searching for shuffle js and load more data and found an answer that I thing this gonna work with my code, but it doesn't.

For the first time load I use this code:

```
var shuffleme = ( function( $ ) {

      var $grid = $('#promogrid'),
          $sizer = $grid.find('.shuffle_sizer'),

  init = function() {
        $grid.shuffle({
              sizer: $sizer
        });
  }

  return {
        init: init
  };
}( jQuery ));

shuffleme.init();
```

In my load more function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/request?process=bp_lm',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {row:row},
        beforeSend:function(){
              $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
        },
        success: function(response) {

              $("#promogrid .shuffle_sizer").before(response.result);
              $grid.shuffle('appended', response.result);

              var rowno = row + rowperpage;

              if(rowno > total) {
                    $('.load_more_btn').hide();
                    $('.hide_data_btn').show();
              } else {
                    $(".load_more_btn").show();
              }

        }
  });
```

The question is, I already use append function that come from shuffle js documentation and it still doesn't work. But, it's working when I click the Load More button in the third times.

The first time I click the button it shows the error :
[image]
[image]

The second time I click the button then appears an error again:
[image]

The last clicked is working:
[image]

Somebody please help me
I don't know what is wrong with my code
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working now when I insert the response.result inside $(). So, it would be

```
$grid.shuffle('appended', $(response.result));
```